# How to make the number in the first label greater than the second label

Tags: .net, vb.net, conditional-statements

I made a program that generates random numbers and places the numbers in two separate labels.
How can I make the number in the first label greater than the number in the second label.

Here is my code for generating random numbers:

```
Dim nRandom As Integer
Dim nRandom1 As Integer
Dim randomgenerator As New Random

'Displays random numbers from 1 to 10
nRandom = randomgenerator.Next(1, 11)
nRandom1 = randomgenerator.Next(1, 11)
'Displays random numbers on the first label
lblNum1.Text = Convert.ToString(nRandom)
'Displays random numbers on the second label
lblNum2.Text = Convert.ToString(nRandom1)
```

I want to make the first number greater than the second because the numbers should be subtracted and im trying to avoid getting negative answers

The program is on windows forms application visual basic

Answer (score 3):

Simply compare the two random numbers you generate. If `nRandom1` is greater than `nRandom`, then assign `nRandom1` to `lblNum1` and `nRandom` to `lblNum2`.

```
If nRandom >= nRandom1 Then
    'nRandom is greater, put it in first textbox
    lblNum1.Text = Convert.ToString(nRandom)
    lblNum2.Text = Convert.ToString(nRandom1)
Else
    'nRandom1 is greater, put it in first textbox
    lblNum1.Text = Convert.ToString(nRandom1)
    lblNum2.Text = Convert.ToString(nRandom)
End If
```

Second approach which permutes the numbers so that nRandom is always greater or equal compared to nRandom1.

```
If nRandom1 > nRandom Then
    'Permute values
    Dim temp As Integer = nRandom
    nRandom = nRandom1
    nRandom1 = temp
End If
lblNum1.Text = Convert.ToString(nRandom)
lblNum2.Text = Convert.ToString(nRandom1)
```

Comment: The numbers might have some significance relative to the labels that we don't know if, though.

Comment: In that case you could permutate nRandom and nRandom1 values.

Comment: Yes, or generate them with constraints.

Comment: Can you give me examples because im new in using visual basic

Comment: @pxtoxp: Maybe you should learn the VB basics (if statements, loops, cases, etc.) before you start coding? I gave an example anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the first number second and use `nRandom1` as the limiter for generating the other. You already use the `minValue` parameter to specify `1` as the argument.

```
nRandom1 = randomgenerator.Next(1, 11)
nRandom = randomgenerator.Next(nRandom1 + 1, 11)
```

`minValue` is inclusive, so we need to adjust it, and you should adjust this to check `nRandom1` doesn't exceed the maximum value.

Comment: Can you edit my code and show me what you are trying to tell me.